# Friendly report names in SQL Azure Reporting

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database

In my app I have a page where I launch the reports from. I have a list box that I populate with the list of reports on my server. But the names that are populated are the file names so of course they don't have proper spacing or capitalization. I want to substitute a more friendly name for a report but do it programatically. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this issue is being resolved in the newest version. The naming of reports was not available in the initial CTP.